# Pegar somente o horário no Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Como faço para pegar somente o horário no Fullcalendar? Estou usando o Fullcalendar para cadastrar os eventos. Os campos são:

> Título, Cor do Evento, Data, Horário, Descrição

No banco de dados, está sendo cadastrado da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando vou editar, aparece com o horário errado, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam como está o código na parte do horário, tentei colocar **id="hour"**, mas parece que não existe no Fullcalendar:

**HTML**

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="hour" name="Hora" data-mask="99:99" class="md-form-control md-static hour" placeholder="Coloque o horário inicial do evento" value="<?php echo date("H:i"); ?>" required>
      <label id="tipoEnvio">Hora:</label>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script src="fullcalendar/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale/pt-br.js'></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     validRange: {
         start: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>'
     },
     header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
     defaultDate: Date(),
     navLinks: true,
     editable: true,
     eventLimit: true,
     eventClick: function(event) {
       $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
       $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);
       $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
       $('#visualizar #title').val(event.title);
       $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
       $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
       $('#visualizar #color').val(event.color);
       $('#visualizar #description').val(event.description);
       $('#visualizar').modal('show');
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       return false;
     }
....
```

**PHP**

```
$data = array();
....
while($listar = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlVisualizar)) {
       list($dia,$mes,$ano) = explode("/",$listar["DataAgenda"]);
      $dataEvento = $ano."-".$mes."-".$dia;
      $linhas['id'] = $listar["IdAgenda"];
      $linhas['title'] = $listar["Titulo"];
      $linhas['start'] = $listar["DataAgenda"];
      $linhas['color'] = $listar["CorAgendamento"];
      $linhas['description'] = $listar["Conteudo"];
      array_push($data,$linhas);
}
   return json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Existe alguma variável no Fullcalendar ou algum meio de pegar somente o horário?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. Incluí essas duas linhas:

```
 $('#visualizar #hour').text(event.start.format('HH:mm:ss'));
 $('#visualizar #hour').val(event.start.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fox.11
amigo, como fez para separar a data da hora? e exibir assim nesse Modal? e também acrescentar esse campo conteúdo, pode me ajudar a fazer no meu calendário também? desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, The Lélis Designer, perdoe-me a demora, só agora que fui ver sua resposta. Segue abaixo:

HTML

```
<div class="visualizar">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="Data" class="form-control" readonly style="font-weight: bold">
    <input type="text" id="hour" name="Data" class="form-control" readonly style="font-weight: bold">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
   $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
     $('#visualizar #hour').text(event.start.format('HH:mm'));

$.ajax({
url:"suapagina.php",
type:"POST",
dataType: 'JSON',
data:{start:start,id:id},

success:function(sucesso){

if(sucesso.hasEvent == false){
   $('#confirmar').modal('show');  // Modal bootstrap  
    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 }else{
  $('#erro').modal('show'); // Modal bootstrap
 }
}
});
```